# Better way to use variables in this function?

Tags: python

I've got a function `get_prefix_lists` with returns two values, each is a list of strings.

I then want to use those lists separately in another function.   My code below is how i've done it but it feels dirty to use the same variable name (`prefixes`) in the `__main__` section.

Is there a less dirty way?

```
def get_prefix_lists():
    """ Get prefixes from netbox with site-aggregate role """
    v4_prefixes = []
    v6_prefixes = []
    for aggregate in nb.ipam.aggregates.filter(rir=['arin','ripe']):
        if aggregate.family == 4:
            v4_prefixes.append(aggregate.prefix)
            for result in nb.ipam.prefixes.filter(family=4, role='aggregate', within_include=aggregate.prefix):
                v4_prefixes.append(result.prefix)
        else:
            v6_prefixes.append(aggregate.prefix)
            for result in nb.ipam.prefixes.filter(family=6, role='aggregate', within_include=aggregate.prefix):
                v6_prefixes.append(result.prefix)
    return v4_prefixes, v6_prefixes

def get_radb_prefixes(prefixes):
    for prefix in prefixes:
        r = requests.get(url=radb_url + 'route/' + prefix + 'AS11111?password=' + radb_mnt_password, headers=headers)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            pass
        elif r.status_code == 404:
            print(f"{prefix} Is in NetBox but not RADB")
        else:
            print(r.status_code, r.text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("V4 check")
    prefixes = get_radb_prefixes(get_prefix_lists()[0])
    print("V6 check")
    prefixes = get_radb_prefixes(get_prefix_lists()[1])
```

Comment: There isn't really a solution to this other than naming the variable something else or naming it `_prefixes`.

Comment: I don't think this is even a problem, although some linters complain I think. You can try variations like `prefix/a_prefix`or `prefixes/some_prefixes`. I think the underscore prefix is borderline, because you hint it as "private" but you are sharing it between the caller and callee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not returning a dictionary?

```
{"v4": [], "v6": []}
```

Here's just some quickly jotted code to better explain:

```
def get_prefix_lists():
    """ Get prefixes from netbox with site-aggregate role """
    prefixes = {}
    prefixes['v4'] = []
    prefixes['v6'] = []
    for aggregate in nb.ipam.aggregates.filter(rir=['arin','ripe']):
        if aggregate.family == 4:
            prefixes['v4'].append(aggregate.prefix)
            for result in nb.ipam.prefixes.filter(family=4, role='aggregate', within_include=aggregate.prefix):
                prefixes['v4'].append(result.prefix)
        else:
            prefixes['v6'].append(aggregate.prefix)
            for result in nb.ipam.prefixes.filter(family=6, role='aggregate', within_include=aggregate.prefix):
                prefixes['v6'].append(result.prefix)
    return prefixes
```